# Looking for a word that reflects both retained and immediate or something inbetween

Tags: names

With programming graphical user interfaces there is the most common one of having a retained mode. There is also the immediate mode.

To explain this a bit more simplified, I will explain it with drawing an ellipse.

In a retained mode it would look something like this:

[image]

In an immediate mode it would look something like this:

[image]

The key thing is that with the immediate it is drawn directly and then it is gone. With the retained we keep the data.
The immediate mode is way easier and more flexible.

I made something in between an immediate and retained mode for graphic user interfaces. I am looking for a word to describe that.
So is there a word that covers both or something in between the words immediate and retained?

Answer (score 1):

extant seems like a good word to describe it, it is something immediate that is saved, or retained.